# Displaying Char And Integer Together

Tags: java, type-conversion

My code is in Java. I have a `char` array that has `int` values as well as `char` values. When I print, I get its values related to ASCII. But when I convert output to `int`, my character value changes to its ASCII value.

```
char arr[]=new char [5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    arr[i]=(char)(i+1);
}

arr[0]='@';

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)                
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Or converting to `int`:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)                
{
   System.out.println((int)arr[i]);
}
```

My output is

> 64 2 3 4 5

or

> @

depending on which code I use. However, I want the output as

> @ 2 3 4 5

I tried using method overloading to separate integers and characters, but that didn't work.

Is there a condition for `int` like below?

```
if(arr[i]==int)
```

The code doesn't work but is there some thing similar to it or any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work, because as far a Java is concerned, a `char` primitive is just a 16 bit unsigned integer value. To demonstrate:

```
System.out.println('A' == 65); // prints true
```

One way to work around this would be to declare an object array, and rely on [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to have Java automatically convert your primitive value to an `Integer` or `Character` wrapper object:

```
Object arr[] = new Object[2];
arr[0] = '@'; // stores '@' as a Character wrapper object
arr[1] = 1; // stores 1 as an Integer wrapper object

for (Object o : arr) {
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Unlike primitives, wrapper objects are aware of their type, so this prints out:

```
@ // by calling Character.toString()
1 // by calling Integer.toString()
```

Note that you lose some compile-time checking in the process. Your object array will not only accept `Character` and `Integer` values, but also any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Robby is very correct! However, if you are just looking for a hack to quickly convert between ints and chars, you can take advantage of the ASCII values and use an offset (48) in this case which is the value for the char `'0'` and then use it to convert between both primitive types. So I used an array to save the resulting integers for output purposes.

```
    public class Hack{
        public static void main(String []args){
                char arr[]=new char [5];
                int offset = 48;

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                        arr[i]=(char)(i+1 + offset);
                }

                //arr[0]='@';

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
                int num_arr[] = new int [5];

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                        num_arr[i]= ( arr[i] - offset);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(num_arr[i]);
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5


1
2
3
4
5
```